# Run custom validation before created form

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular7

I have a form with custom validation.
I need validate the form, cause the form will be undefined. If I don't do this, the code is not working. Validation is working at now with this code, but I will try improve it.

When the pageloading finished, the program went into validation (twice) and wrote my message to console (before the form created). I think something wrong. Until I open the dialog/form or finished form creation, it shouldn't run.

```js
  createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.local_user.name, [Validators.required, this.isExistValidator()]]
    });
  }
```

```js
isExistValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      if (this.form) {
        // some code with reutrn isExist:true or null
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Seems like a XY problem...you really should be asking if how you're creating your form is correct i.e.

Comment: If you have any suggestion just put it. I'm a beginner, so I will be glad for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way

```
isExistValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
       if (!control || !control.parent) {
          return null;
       }
       ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this custom validation appropriate? Or could it be nicer? I'm beginner angular programmer.